# How can I validate another model when viewing details of one model?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

I am showing a details page of a Movie model with the list of related (child elements) Actor models.

At the bottom of the Actor list, I am rendering a textbox for quick insertion of new Actor related to the current Movie, and this works fine.

But, how can I validate (client and server) the textbox for actors name so it's not empty on submit?

I am using Linq2SQL and DataAnnotations:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ActorValidation))]
partial class Actor
{
}


public class ActorValidation
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You forgot the name.")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

This is the form on Movie details view:

```
    <% 
        Html.EnableClientValidation();
        using (Html.BeginForm("NewActor", "Movie"))
        { 
    %>
    <%= Html.Hidden("MovieId", Model.Id) %>
    <%= Html.TextBox ("Name")%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Name") %>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to put your "new actor" form into a separate Partial View that uses an Actor as its model and then call `Html.RenderPartial` to render it. That's what I'd do.

This works particularly well with AJAX, because you can just validate the model and return the Partial View with the validation method enabled on failure. On success, you can return a partial view that shows the new Actor, followed by a fresh instance of the "new actor" form.